# phpunit w/ laravel: missing argument when using providers

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, provider

I'm running PHPUnit w/ Laravel. Here's my test:

```
class UserTest extends TestCase {

public function testSluggifyReturnsSluggifiedString($originalString, $expectedResult)
{
    $url = new User();
    $result = $url->sluggify($originalString);

    $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $result);

}
public function providerTestSluggifyReturnsSluggifiedString()
{
    return array(
        array('This string will be sluggified', 'this-string-will-be-sluggified'),
        array('THIS STRING WILL BE SLUGGIFIED', 'this-string-will-be-sluggified'),
        array('This1 string2 will3 be 44 sluggified10', 'this1-string2-will3-be-44-sluggified10'),
        array('This! @string#$ %$will ()be "sluggified', 'this-string-will-be-sluggified'),
        array("Tänk efter nu – förr'n vi föser dig bort", 'tank-efter-nu-forrn-vi-foser-dig-bort'),
        array('', '')
    );
}
```

}

As I'm familiarizing myself w/ unit testing, I've simply added the `sluggify()` function to the bottom of the User class.

I get this error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) UserTest::testSluggifyReturnsSluggifiedString
ErrorException: Missing argument 1 for UserTest::testSluggifyReturnsSluggifiedString()
```

If I change the test to define the two arguments (`public function testSluggifyReturnsSluggifiedString($originalString='test', $expectedResult='test')`) The test runs fine. For some reason it's not reading the provider data.

I suspect this is something about the Laravel setup, but I can't find anything in the docs to point me in the right direction. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHPUnit docs on [Data Provider](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers):

> The data provider method to be used is specified using the @dataProvider annotation.

So you have to add the annotation on top of your test method, for example:

```
class UserTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * @dataProvider providerTestSluggifyReturnsSluggifiedString
     */
    public function testSluggifyReturnsSluggifiedString($originalString, $expectedResult)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function providerTestSluggifyReturnsSluggifiedString()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```